# mitm transparent mode blocking Instagram app

Tags: mitmproxy

Im testing MITM proxy, i need to track some url in my home network, tracking its not the problem, i use transparent mode, youtube works fine, only instagram and facebook i cant make work.
i know that they have something to prevent mitm, but also youtube.
i use mitm proxy to track only one domain, example "me.com", but when active i cant open facebook and instaram app.
There is any way for the MITM Proxy effective ignore instagram and facebook? im only interested in one domain.

- system for mitm - windows 10
- system for the target ios 16

I tried use transparente mode, works, but the app for instagram and face its not ignored.
i need to track one domain only without brake instagram and facebook.

Comment: It is possible that Instagram uses TLS fingerprinting and thus identifies the client as Python based client. As Python is mostly used for web scrapers and other tools the companies don't like they block Python completly.

Comment: But do you think its possible to work around it? i just need to track one domain only.

Comment: If it is really TLS fingerprinting then this would be difficult to bypass, only using a different TLS intercepting proxy would be an option but I don't know one that supports transparent mode. As you are on Windows you could try ti install Fiddler Classic and configure it in Mitmproxy as upstream proxy. Fiddler Classic is DotNet based and the Dotnet TLS fingerprint is usually not blacklisted.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:
a) launch mitmproxy with ignore-hosts in this case you can set "what to ignore" or what not...for example:
mitmproxy -p 8080 --ignore-hosts '^(?!.*?(car)).*$'
this command launch mitmproxy and ignore everything (so let fb an ig work) but track only hosts that contain car in the host name
b) you can write a filter in python and launch it, for example

this is filter.py
def request(flow):
if not any(keyword in flow.request.host for keyword in ['car']):
flow.ignore()
and launch mitmproxy with the filter
mitmproxy -s filter.py -p 8080

in case b will allow all traffic if is not included in filter

Comment: Thank you. 
Let me ask you one thing. 
For example, if I want to track only google domain and subdomains, I use “google” instead “car” (in your example) or use —-allow-hosts to do, to “not ignore” only google urls”.